# PhpStorm Emmet doesn't work with Tab but with Space

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, emmet

I can't think of a solution for this...

When I set my Emmet settings (Settings->Editor->Emmet) to autocomplete things with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, PhpStorm will just insert a regular tab space and not complete the Emmet syntax.

Example:
`.card.card-default` autocompletes to

```html
<div class="card card-default">

</div>
```

BUT only when I set the key to <kbd>Space</kbd> and not to <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
Please help me on this one.

I've tried resetting the whole IDE settings, uninstalled all plugins, unbound every Tab-hotkey but nothing worked.

Comment: 1) What's your OS and IDE version? 2) What Keymap is used? 3) Does `Tab` works if you try to use it "normal" code completion (e.g. HTML tag, JS or PHP function etc)? 4) If you go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and use "Find Actions by Shortcut" button (the one next to the local search field)and press `Tab` there, what actions will it show? Show a screenshot. 5) Will it work if you try to expand things like `dl+` or `mn` (in HTML context)?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. When I set it to space, completion works fine. Here is a screenshot of shortcuts using tab: https://paste.artichokenetwork.com/s/7ru1wwxo.png. I'm using Phpstorm 2022.3.2 via Gateway on Ubuntu 22.10.